# Generating a reproducible unique ID in Spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

We have a data lake containing tons of files, where I can read these the contents of the files along with their paths:

```
sdf = spark.read.load(source)\
  .withColumn("_path", F.input_file_name())
```

**I would like to generate a unique ID for each row, for easier downstream joining between tables, and I want this ID to be reproducible between runs.**

---

**Simplest approach** is to simply use the `_path` column as the identifier.

```py
sdf.withColumn("id", F.col("_path"))
```

However, it would be "prettier" and more compact to have some kind of integer representation. And for other tables the unique identifier could be a combination of a few columns, uglyfying this a bit more.

**Another approach** is to use [monotonically increasing ID](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id).

```
sdf.withColumn("id", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
```

However, in this solution there is no guarantee that when running the analysis id=2 is also id=2 when the analysis is run a week later (when new data has arrived).

**A third approach** is to use the hashing function:

```py
sdf.withColumn("id", F.hash("_path"))
```

Which could be quite nice, because it is easy to hash a combination of columns, *but* this is not stable since multiple inputs *can* give the same output:

Running such analysis on our actual data gave 396,702 hash-ids from a single origin `_path`, and 24 hash-ids originating from two paths. Hence a collision rate of 0.006%.

**We *could* simply disregard this very small portion of the data, but there must be a more elegant way of achieving what I want to achieve?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the `xxhash64` hash in Spark SQL, which gives a 64-bit hash value and should be more robust to hash collisions:

```
sdf.withColumn("id", F.expr("xxhash64(_path)"))
```

or to use more robust hashing algorithms,

```
sdf.withColumn("id", F.expr("conv(sha2(_path,256),16,10)"))
```

Comment: This appears to eliminate all my current collisions. Sweet! Still curious, however, as to whether there are alternative approaches not relying on a hashing function?

Comment: @casparjespersen I don't quite understand the rationale for generating ids. If it's totally random, why are you generating it?

Comment: Another approach would be to generate a row number based on some ordering, but that would be inefficient for large datasets.

Comment: It's not totally random. Imagine a situation where each row has a `user_id` and `date_collected`, for instance. Multiple rows can contain the same `(user_id, date_collected)` combination, and this combination we can call a "user_upload". We now make a downstream table based on this (along with other aggregated information). We want to be able to refer to rows in this table somehow, and carrying around the exact originating combination is cumbersome.

Comment: We're building a relational data model with business logic on top of an event-based data collection.

Comment: I see. I think hashing is probably okay, if you want to be even more robust, you can use sha512 which has a super low collision probability. xxhash64 is not quite robust from a quick Google.